# Raspbian download on Windows

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, software-installation, raspbian-wheezy

I know this is not entirely or completely a Raspberry Pi question, but I am sure many people could help me out with what is going on and possibly had the same situation.

I am looking to download Raspbian for my memory card for my Raspberry Pi 2.  I know you can get that, as well as NOOBS and other OS's at the Raspberry Pi site.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ 
I have done this in the past (about a year and half ago) a couple times without any problems and much success.  Long story short, my SD cards are bad, got new cards, need a new download and install and didn't save what I previously had (I think it was Wheezy).

I am using Windows to do the download and eventually to do the disk image (I don't currently have access to other OS's, but I do have access to a wide a variety of Windows OS).
Currently, every time I try to download using the link provided, it will eventually stall and then try to auto-open the zip and then say that the file is corrupt.
I know the site is not having problems, and I know how to prevent Chrome, IE, Mozilla from auto-opening the zip file.  What is odd though is that the downloaded files each time are a different size, and always a different size than what is listed in the download amount (typically the download status bar says 1.4 GB which seems right, but the zip file is usually between 200MB and 600MB...all the while downloading on a gigabit ethernet it will say about 37+ mins remaining to download but complete in about 5).

What is the size amount that I should be looking for with this?
Has anyone else encountered similar problems recently, especially from the RaspberryPi.org website?

Comment: The size amount varies because of where in the process the download fails. You can check the integrity of the download (which is better than a file size) by using the checksum that appears next to the download link. Several tools to compute a checksum on windows can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478722/what-is-the-best-way-to-calculate-a-checksum-for-a-file-that-is-on-my-machine. also

Comment: if you are having difficulty getting a good download you may want to use the Torrent download instead. You may also want to make sure that you are saving the file not running it when downloading (this should prevent the file auto opening). This option will usually allow you to restart a failed download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get good version of the download from the RaspberryPi.org site finally.
Update on other parts of the issue...I have been trying this since Tuesday (about 5 days on and off over the weekend and holiday).  The version without Pixel, the Noobs downloads, all for the Torrent and Zip version were experiencing the same issues in general.  The torrent using BitTorrent would also time-out and give an error.  The checksum helped identify that there was an error and that the supposedly complete file was bad, but this was kinda apparent when I would try to install the system.  Overall a good tip in general, thank you Steve Robillard.

In general, had to make sure that auto-open downloads was not turned on for Chrome.

For other people curious.
The ZIP file is about 1.48 GB downloaded and an uncompressed IMG file is about 4.25 GB.  This is of the current available download from the Raspberry Pi site for Raspbian Jessie w/ Pixel (file updated date is 9/23/2016).

Patience was the #1 thing overall.  I am not sure if it was the server traffic, the server itself or something on my end (though I was able to download a bunch of other things easily and quickly).  It took about 70 minutes, and I had to make sure not much else was going on my computer (its a brand new HP ZBook, so it also wasn't the computer itself), especially downloads or other similar requests.

Comment: `The ZIP file is about 1.48 GB downloaded` - about is as useful as not knowing at all ... that's why all the downloads have sha-1 checksums associated with them, so, you don't need to know the file size, just that the checksum is correct

Answer (score 0):

Howzit mate.

I personally have not come across this problem. However I can provide you and possibly other people with a solution, not only for getting Raspberry pi OS images but other Linux Distros as well. What I normally do is google the term "raspbian parent directory" then you will get some good results. Sometime you can look for a mirror share in your country or area that will give you way faster speeds and reliable data.

As an example have a look [here](http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/raspberrypi/raspbian/images/). An FTP site with pretty much all you could ask for.

Comment: This is a relatively risky approach - be *extremely* careful that you know who's serving the files and that they're trustworthy. The FTP link you've provided appears to be hosted a Japanese education institution and is *probably* OK, although there's no real way of knowing who put it there. I'd recommend the torrent download link from the Pi Foundation over this approach.

Comment: I should have mention that you should choose educational institutions over anything else. They mainly provide safe fast sites anyways.